# Horizontal inline list with nested child lists

Tags: html, css

I have a list with child elements like :

```
<ul>
    <li>.. </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>.. </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li></li>
</ul>

<style> li {float: left; margin-left: 10px }  li ul {float: left} </style>
```

This is fine in Firefox, all the list elements being inline horizontally like I want.

`LI   LI   LI    LI   LI`

When I look  in Chrome though those child elements are dropped below the main list elements like this :

```
LI     LI                LI
           LI     LI
```

I tried `display: inline` on all of the elements but it made no difference.

What is the best cross browser way to create a horizontal row of list elements that have nested children like this?

Here is a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/7yufQ/1/

In Firefox the numbers are screwed up from the floats and Chrome shows them as in my example above.

Comment: Use reset.css like file to have the same initial styles for all browsers.

Comment: Why are the items nested if you just want them all inline?

Comment: Can you show us the problem with a live link to your site or a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) / [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) demo?

Comment: That's a huge overkill for what he needs. Also, it's been long debated that normalizing the CSS is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style> 
    ul{
      padding:0px;
      margin:0px;
      list-style-type:none;
      }
    li {float: left; margin-left: 10px }  
    li ul {float: left;} 
</style>
```

here is an example, works fine for me in Chrome as well

http://jsfiddle.net/corotchi/8BLck/

Comment: I do have a reset in the css too so these elements do have 0 padding and margin unless I add.

Comment: Thanks for you help, I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can make both `ul` and `li`s inline.

http://jsfiddle.net/QFjgH/

```
ul, li {
 display: inline;   
}

li { margin-left: 10px; }
```

Comment: Hmm yes I have tried that.. there must be something else in the code interfering.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is whitespace after the "2". I just removed it an put the `<ul>` next to the "2" and it works just fine in Chrome. Look http://jsfiddle.net/7yufQ/2/