# ol inside li causing problems

Tags: html, css

I have the following code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 

    <style>
.nav{
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-width:1px 0;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: #333;
}
.navLi{
    display:inline;
}
.nav ol{
  display:flex;

}
.nav a{
    display:inline-block;

    padding:10px;
 text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    color:white;
}
.green{
    background-color:green;
}
.blue{
    background-color:blue;
}
.sideBar{
width:25%;
background:#333;
height: 850px;
}
.whiteColor{
  color:white;
}
.paragraph{
    padding: 20px;
    line-height: 150%;
    font-family: ariel;

}
.div1{
width: 75%;
background: white;
}
.textSize{
  font-size: 1px;
}
.div2{
    border:solid 1px;
    display:flex;
}
.image{
float:left;
}
.maxDiv{
    max-width: 1000px;
     margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    border: 3px solid green;
    padding: 10px;
}

    </style>


</head>
<body>
<div class="maxDiv">
<div  id="myTopnav">
<ul class="nav">
 <li class="navLi"> <a href="givataiim.html" class = "green">0</a></li>
  <li  class="navLi"><a href="#news" >1</a></li>
  <li  class="navLi"><a href="#contact">2</a></li>
  <li  class="navLi"><a href="#about">3</a></li>
  <li  class="navLi"><a href="#about">4</a></li>
  <li  class="navLi"><a href="rishon.html" class = "blue">5</a></li>
  <li  class="navLi"><a href="#about">6</a></li>
  <li  class="navLi"><a href="hw9.html">7</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I want each of the li to have an ordered list below it (I know that it won't look pretty)
I tried making an ol element and some li inside of it and it looks weird.
When I do the ol inside each li and inside that ol I put some li it looks something like:

[image]

Code :

```
 <li class="navLi"> <a href="1.html" class = "green">0</a>
 <ol>
  <li  class="navLi"><a href="#news" >1</a></li>
  <li  class="navLi"><a href="#news" >1</a></li>
 </ol>
 </li>
```

The ol inside the li looks not good as marked in the red square in the photo.

Any idea ?

Comment: When nesting lists you need to make new CSS rules for the nested lists, as they will be appeared inside and also stretch their parent li.

Comment: Thanks for the response, what rules ?

Comment: You need to play with the nested OL's display, position and width/height properties. If I knew which visual result you were after, I could give you a working example.

Comment: take a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268481/horizontal-inline-list-with-nested-child-lists

Answer (score 1):

You can hover 4 to see a submenu. I cleaned up the CSS, deleted classes/IDs I couldn't find being used.
The submenu has absolute positioning. Both menus are now defined using flexbox.

```css
.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navLi {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: relative;
}

.nav ol {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 1px;
}

.navLi:hover ol {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.navLi:hover ol li {
  padding: 14px 16px;
}

a {
  display: block;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #333;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: white;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.maxDiv {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 3px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="maxDiv">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="navLi"><a href="givataiim.html" class="green">0</a></li>
    <li class="navLi"><a href="#news">1</a></li>
    <li class="navLi"><a href="#contact">2</a></li>
    <li class="navLi"><a href="#about">3</a></li>
    <li class="navLi"><a href="#about">4</a>
      <ol>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="navLi"><a href="rishon.html" class="blue">5</a></li>
    <li class="navLi"><a href="#about">6</a></li>
    <li class="navLi"><a href="hw9.html">7</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```